# spring-cloud-loabalancer configuring static server list

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

We're moving away from the spring-cloud Netflix OSS ecosystem one step at a time. Currently we're implementing spring-cloud-loadbalancer and removing Ribbon.
However we used to have a lot of static services in our integration tests, now with the move from ribbon towards spring-cloud-loadbalancer those properties are not being picked up any longer.
i.e.:

```
foo-service.ribbon.NIWSServerListClassName=com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
foo-service.ribbon.listOfServers=localhost:9876
```

We've migrated towards using spring-cloud-loadbalancer in the following way 
First we annotated our Webclient.Builder with @LoadBalanced like this

```
@Bean
@LoadBalanced
fun webClientBuilder() = WebClient.builder()
```

And then we've added the @LoadBalancerClient annotation on the client classes like this

```
@LoadBalancerClient(name = "foo-service", configuration = [FooServiceConfiguration::class])
class FooServiceClient(private val basicAuthWebClient: WebClient)
```

This results in our tests failing with an UnknownHostException for foo-service.

Now My question is how do we configure this static server list in the new spring-cloud-loadbalancer?

Comment: ribbon properties don't work for spring cloud loadbalancer. You can use `spring.cloud.discovery.client.simple.*` properties. See https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-commons/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix.html

Comment: @J.Pip Which property did you end up using from the ```spring.cloud.discovery.client.simple``` instead of the ```NIWSServerListClassName``` ?

Comment: Looks like the ribbon related configs like ```NIWSServerListClassName``` wont work with spring cloud

Answer (score 4):

Based on @spencergibb's comment, I guess something like this should work:

````
spring:
  cloud:
    discovery:
      client:
        simple:
          instances:
            foo-service:
              - instanceId: foo1
                serviceId: foo-service
                host: localhost
                port: 9876```
````

Comment: What would be the instanceId here?

Comment: If you have multiple instances registered, each should have an unique value.: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/95ce58741d0506111a562fb7ec8de2c1a79c44b9/spring-cloud-commons/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/client/ServiceInstance.java#L31